# Vertically align <div> contained in <td>

Tags: html, css

I have something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="blue">...</div>
    <div class="yellow">...</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="blue">...</div>
    <div class="yellow">...</div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here's a example of my current HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/DcRmu/2/

Inside a `<tr>`, all `<td>`s have the same height. I want the yellow `<div>`s inside those `<td>`s to align vertically along the bottom of `<td>`; and the blue `<div>`s to align vertically along the top of `<td>`. I tried to set `vertical-align` to `bottom` and it didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `<td valign="bottom">`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`vertical-align:bottom;` should work

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/DcRmu/

<strike>**EDIT**</strike>

*As per the new fiddle*

You just need to place `vertical-align:bottom;` on the `td` not on the `div`

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/DcRmu/7/

**EDIT 2**

I reread the question again and I saw the change

> I want the yellow `<div>`s inside those `<td>`s to align vertically along
>   the bottom of `<td>`; and the blue `<div>`s to align vertically along the
>   top of `<td>`

To do this, you need to

1. set the `vertical-align` to `top` on the `td`
2. float the `div`s
3. give the bottom `div` a `margin` equal to the height of the cell minus the sum of the `div` heights. In this case, 200px - (50px + 50px) = 100px.

New CSS

```
tr td{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    vertical-align:top;
}

div.blue{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
}
div.yellow{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:yellow;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/DcRmu/9/

Comment: Sorry I just clarified my question. Please see the link http://jsfiddle.net/DcRmu/2/. Thanks!

Comment: I just reread the question @garthcn.  And I edited my answer again. ;-)